# C++ REST SDK How to check if http address is invalid

Tags: c++, rest, http, casablanca

I am using the C++ REST SDK for a small console application to test a server with a variety of http queries. Everything works fine, except for if the server is invalid (as in it doesn't exist), the program stalls for 10 seconds and then crashes. I can't find anything in the documentation that clues me into what is going on.  Every other case I can handle just fine, but I can't figure out how to check if the server is valid beforehand so I can handle this error. Here's the part of the code where it always hangs up:

```
web::http::client::http_client newClient(queries[index], config);
web::http::http_response response = newClient.request(web::http::methods::GET).get();
```

I think that if the server is invalid, the .get() doesn't know what to return and that's why the program shuts down, but I'm not sure. Please point me in the right direction on how to fix this.

Comment: There are a lot of things that can go wrong.  No DNS?  Port not open?  I don't even know what library you're using.

Comment: C++ REST SDK is the library. I'm purposefully using a server I know won't work so I know what will happen when the end user accidentally tells it to use the wrong server or failed to set it up correctly -- the program works perfectly fine if it's fed the IP address to a server that works. I simply need to know if there is any way to check if a given server is accessible before I read the response from it using REST SDK.

Comment: That's an incredibly confusing name for a library.

Comment: Does it crash right after the `request()` line? Is there a check on `response` to see if the returned value was valid?

Comment: Yes, it crashes while its processing the request line. I put a cout right after it , and it never printed anything to the console before it crashed so the problem must be with that line.

Comment: Might be in the `.get()` then. Try to call this only, to see where the problem is: `newClient.request(web::http::methods::GET)`

Comment: It seems like the .get() is necessary, the library uses task-based programming classes and without the .get(), you just return a task object which I can't get any meaningful data out of.

Comment: Yes, it sure is needed, but you could split the calls to finetune your problem. For example: `_some_type_ request_result = newClient.request(web::http::methods::GET);` and then `request_reult.get();`.

Comment: Ok, I did that and the problem does seem to be with the .get() function. It must not know how to handle the case where it gets no data from the server, or maybe it's timing out because it keeps trying to reach the server and can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
web::http::http_response response = newClient.request(web::http::methods::GET).get();
```

-> You are calling `.get()` on a retrun value from `request()` which is probably invalid. So you might try to split up as follows:

```
_some_type_ request_result = newClient.request(web::http::methods::GET);
```

(you'll have to look up what `_some_type_` needs to be)

Check `request_result`, and if it's ok call:

```
request_result.get();
```

Else, provide a error message.

Comment: Great, that fixed it! Thank you for your help and clear answer!